# Primitive elements of finite dimensional Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

An element $x$ of a Hopf algebra $H$, is called *a primitive element* if $\Delta(x)=1\otimes x+x\otimes 1$. The set of primitive elements of $H$ is denoted $P(H)$. It can be shown that:

"*If $H$ is a $\mathbb{k}$-Hopf algebra of finite $\mathbb{k}$-dimension and $\mathbb{k}$ is a field of characteristic zero, then $P(H)=\{0\}$*"

The proof of the above fact, amounts to showing -inductively- that, if there is $0\neq x \in P(H)$ then $x^{n}$ (for all positive integers $n$) are linearly independent, which is a contradiction to the finite dimensionality of $H$. See for example at [Hopf algebras - an introduction (Dascalescu-Nastasescu-Raianu)](https://books.google.gr/books?id=pBJ6sbPHA0IC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), exercise 4.2.16.

**Now the question:** If we drop the requirement of characteristic zero (for the field $\mathbb{k}$ of coefficients) what are some examples violating the above proposition? In other words, considering hopf algebras over some finite field, are there -explicit- examples of primitive elements?

Comment: crossposted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249902/primitve-elements-in-group-hopf-algebras-over-fields-of-non-zero-characteristic

Answer (score 3):

How about this one: Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $2$ and $R=F[x]$ the polynomial ring over $F$ in one variable. $R$ becomes a Hopf algebra by making $x$ a primitive element, i.e. $\Delta(x)=1\otimes x + x\otimes 1$, $\epsilon(x)=0$ and $S(x)=-x=x$. The ideal $I=\langle x^2\rangle$ is a Hopf ideal, because $$\Delta(x^2)=(1\otimes x + x\otimes 1)^2 = 1\otimes x^2 + 2x\otimes x + x^2\otimes 1 = 1\otimes x^2 + x^2\otimes 1 \in R\otimes I + I\otimes R.$$
Hence $H=R/I$ is a two-dimensional commutative, cocommutative Hopf algebra with primitive element $\overline{x}=x+I$.